# Linq Query with Null for Related Field

Tags: c#, linq, nullreferenceexception, nullable

I'm having some trouble saving and retrieving related records using EF 6 and Linq.

I have two related entities, Vehicle and Transactions. When entering a transaction, the user selects the vehicle from a combobox before saving the transaction. Vehicle is not a required field on the Transaction and sometimes a transaction doesn't have a related vehicle. Currently I am checking to see if the combobox is null using the code below before attempting to add the vehicle to the transaction.

```
if ( !string.IsNullOrEmpty( row.Cells[3].FormattedValue as String ) )
{
    // A truck has been selected
    int iSelectedVehicle;
    if ( int.TryParse( row.Cells[3].Value.ToString(), out iSelectedVehicle ) )
    {
        oTransaction.Vehicle = db.Vehicles.First( v => v.ID == iSelectedVehicle );
    }

}
```

This seems to work okay until I try to retrieve the transactions with a Linq query. When the query executes I get

```
"Object reference not set to an instance of an object."
```

because the Vehicle field is null. How can I handle this situation? I tried marking the Vehicle field in the Transaction as nullable, but since it's a virtual field,
it didn't work, I get an error "The type Vehicle must be a non-nullable value...."

This is what my models look like (abbreviated):

```
public class Transaction
{
    [Key]
    public int ID { get; set; }

    ...

    public virtual Vehicle Vehicle { get; set; }

    ...
}

public class Vehicle
{
    [Key]
    public int ID { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Index]
    public int VehicleNumber { get; set; }

    ...
}
```

And here is my query:

```
var transactions = ( from t in db.Transactions.AsEnumerable()
                     select new
                     {
                         Product = t.Product.ProductCode,
                         Description = t.Product.Description,
                         Transaction_Type = t.TransactionType.AddRemove,
                         Quantity = t.TransactionType.AddRemove == "Addition"
                                 ? t.FullQuantity + ( t.PartialQuantity / t.Product.Pieces )
                                 : -1 * ( t.FullQuantity + ( t.PartialQuantity / t.Product.Pieces ) ),
                         //Truck = t.Vehicle.VehicleNumber.ToString() ?? string.Empty, // This is the error line. I was trying to check for null but...
                         POJob = t.SourceNumber,
                         Transaction_Date = t.TransactionDate,
                         RecordedBy = t.User.Name,
                         RecordedDate = t.CreateDate
                     } ).ToList();
```

It seems like this would be a fairly common situation but I can't seem to get around it.

I'm using Code First with Windows Forms.

UPDATE

Revised query based on Philip Smith's answer below:

```
var transactions = ( from t in db.Transactions.DefaultIfEmpty()
                                     select new
                                     {
                                         Product = t.Product.ProductCode,
                                         Description = t.Product.Description,
                                         Transaction_Type = t.TransactionType.AddRemove,
                                         Quantity = t.TransactionType.AddRemove == "Addition"
                                                 ? t.FullQuantity + ( t.PartialQuantity / t.Product.Pieces )
                                                 : -1 * ( t.FullQuantity + ( t.PartialQuantity / t.Product.Pieces ) ),
                                         Truck = t.Vehicle == null ? string.Empty : t.Vehicle.VehicleNumber.ToString(),
                                         POJob = t.SourceNumber,
                                         Transaction_Date = t.TransactionDate,
                                         CreatedBy = t.CreatedBy.Name,
                                         CreatedDate = t.CreateDate,
                                         LastUpdatedBy = t.LastUpdatedBy.Name,
                                         LastUpdated = t.LastUpdatedDate,
                                     } ).ToList();
```

This produces a different error: {"The specified argument value for the function is not valid. [ Argument # = 2,Name of function(if known) = case ]"}

Comment: So if the `Vehicle` property on the `Transaction` object is null, you want to skip over that record? You *could* be getting `The type Vehicle must be a non-nullable value` because you have it set as being `Required`.

Comment: I still want to retrieve the record but with Vehicle field blank. I have the VehicleNumber required, but that's in the Vehicle model, not in the transactions model.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The use of `t.Vehicle.VehicleNumber` will generate the error if `t.Vehicle` is null.

Try:

```
 t.Vehicle == null ? string.Empty : t.Vehicle.VehicleNumber.ToString();
```

This tests the correct item for null.

Comment: Thanks @philip, when I substitute the line in the query with the one above, I get **{"The specified argument value for the function is not valid. [ Argument # = 2,Name of function(if known) = case ]"}** and I took the "required" out of the Vehicles model, and I revised the query above based on your answer.

Comment: I think I got it! As I was working on figuring this out I changed `from t in db.Transactions.AsEnumerable()` to `from t in db.Transactions.DefaultIfEmpty()` When I changed it back to AsEnumerable() everything seems to work using the line you provided. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You can also add the builder class a initialize, especially if it is a list...

```
public class Transaction
{


public Transaction()
{
 this.Vehicle = new Vehicle ();

}

[Key]
    public int ID { get; set; }
    ...

    public Vehicle Vehicle { get; set; }

    ...
}
```